# How to have Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 together on Windows XP?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have installed Internet Explorer 8 on my Windows XP. Is there any method to install Internet Explorer 7 on my computer? I need to have both versions installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE Browser Testing for Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796229/ie-browser-testing-for-windows-7)

Comment: This is a dupe of 1796229 and about 100 others.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [This](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) it is virtualPc's preinstalled wit different internet explorer versions.

As an alternative you have at look at [SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Features.aspx) where you can test multiple version in one window.

Comment: +1 virtualisation is the *only* way to get the completely accurate behaviour of IE7. IE8's compatibility mode is close (close enough for many purposes) but not exactly the same. The hacks that let you load multiple IE versions on a single Windows installation are highly unreliable.

Comment: @bobince: [This hack](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) works fine here.

Comment: Works fine for simple pages. Can easily fall over for more complicated cases, especially where JScript or various auth situations are involved.

Comment: +1 for VPC, -1 for SuperPreview.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to have both installed, but you can run IE8 in [compatibility mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-compatibility-view), which may serve your purposes just as well.

Comment: And is it Exactly the same like when I use IE7?

Comment: @josiph Yes it is; check out the feature description here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/features/easier.aspx  "Click the Compatibility View toolbar button to display the website as viewed in Internet Explorer 7"

Answer (score 0):

Get [Internet Explorer Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm). It installs any or all of IE versions in a kind of portable virtualization mode. Works perfect. Also installs the Developer Toolbar for IE 5.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

IETester is a free WebBrowser that allows you to have the rendering and javascript engines of IE9 preview, IE8, IE7 IE 6 and IE5.5 on Windows 7, Vista and XP, as well as the installed IE in the same process.

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

I'm using in on Windows 7 but as it says above, it runs on XP too.